# template {{#with}} crash form field value retrieval

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm using this code to retrieve the form fields in a page.

Javascript file:

```
'click #btnSave' : function() {
  var params = {'formField1':'','formField2':''};
  for (var key in params) {
    if (key in this)
      params[key] = this[key].value;      
    }

  // ... database save logic

}
```

There's a '**data**' helper which returns a database object in edition

HTML Form:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="formField1">Field 1</label>
    <input id="formField1" value="{{data.formField1}}">
    <button id="btnSave" type="button">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried to use the **"with"** in the template this way:

```
<form>
  <div>
    {{#with data}}
    <label for="formField1">Field 1</label>
    <input id="formField1" value="{{formField1}}">
    <button id="btnSave" type="button">Save</button>
    {{/with}}
  </div>
</form>
```

But this makes my form data retrieval function useless. Can somebody explain this effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `{{#with data}}` because data is the object itself.

e.g

```
data = {"formField1":"value", "formField2":"value2"}
```

If you had a key called data you could reference data with `{{#with data}}`

```
data = { "data" : { "formField1":"value", "formField2":"value2" } };
```